# Как получить путь к каталогу из TreeView в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Раньше было так: `ShellTreeView1.Path;`  *(очень давно, но так было)*
И получали путь к каталогу.
А теперь `TreeView1.[ ? ]`
Т.е. как получить путь к каталогу?

P.S. Ещё было это:
`ShellTreeView1.Root:=(Path_Destination+Form3.edit1.text)` - тоже считаю, было удобно. Неужели всё убрали?

Comment: посмотрите этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15654349/3373603), возможно поможет

Comment: Кто  куда убрал? В ShellTreeView и Path и Root никуда не делись, а TreeView никогда и не знал о путях...

Comment: Компонент `ShellTreeView` доступен в Delphi вплоть до версии XE6. Его так же можно установить и в более поздние версии: [Where is TShellTreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34909650/6219657) А `TreeView` совершенно другой компонент, не имеющий ничего общего с `ShellTreeView` и нельзя говорить, что в нём что-то убрали или добавили.

Comment: @MBo, таки в поиске задал ShellTreeView - его нет. А в 7-ке был.

Comment: @zed, если я правильно понимаю, то в 7-ке он шёл в стоке, а в последующих идёт допом. Который изначально не выведен в интерфейс VCL?
Завтра попробую установить его.

Answer (score 2):

`TTreeView` - это компонент для отображения данных в виде дерева, про пути он ничего не знает.

Если вы хотите отобразить там структуру каталогов, то вам для начала нужно построить эту структуру в памяти, т.е. собрать некую `TDirStructCollection`, а потом отобразить ее на компоненте. При этом можно к каждому `TTreeNode` привязать свой `TDirStructItem` (элемент вашей структуры данных) и потом получать к нему доступ через свойство `Data`.

```
type
  TDirStructItem = class
  public
    DirPath: string;
  end;

var
  NextDirItem: TDirStructItem;
  Root: TTreeNode;
  Path: string;
begin
  // проходим по структуре состоящей из TDirStructItem  
  Root := tv1.Items.AddObject(nil, 'root', RootDirItem);
  // ...
  tv1.Items.AddChildObject(Root, 'child', NextDirItem);
  // и т.д.

  // из конкретного TreeNode получаем путь
  Path := TDirStructItem(tv1.Items.Item[i].Data).DirPath;
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

Воспользовался функцией `SelectDirectory`.
Просто и более, менее удобно для быстрого программирования:

```
Path := 'C:\';
  if FileCtrl.SelectDirectory(Path, [sdAllowCreate, sdPerformCreate, sdPrompt],SELDIRHELP) then
Edit1.Text := Path;
```

---

*UPD. Иногда, от программки, которая делает лишь backup, многого и не требуется.

Speed run coding есть и иногда стоит к нему прибегать, когда надо что-то навоять для внутреннего пользования и не тратя много на это времени.

Не коммерческий продакшн ведь.

По началу вообще хотел cmd-шку сделать. Но решил потренировать мозг себе.

А тут гуру налетели, дескать - сложное программирование, есть тру программирование!

Я просто удивился, что прожект в Delphi 7 нормально компилировался, в XE ругнулся на ShellTreeView. Вот и всего лишь.*
P.S. Иногда в жизни важен лишь результат.

Comment: Если нужно просто выбрать папку, то ваш вариант однозначно быстрее :)

Comment: @kot-da-vinci - от программки, которая лишь делает backup другого и не требуется.
Speed run coding иногда стоит к нему прибегать.
По началу вообще хотел cmd-шку сделать.
Но решил потренировать мозг себе.
А тут гуру налетели, дескать - сложное программирование, есть тру программирование!
Я просто удивился, что листинг в 7-ке нормально компилировался, в XE ругнулась на ShellTreeView. Вот и всего лишь.

Comment: Неплохой ответ, но на какой-то другой вопрос, а не на заданный. Лучше уберите.